# How to write this formula on an easier way?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to write that on each cell:

```
A1: =SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"1";$I$7:$I$100;">0")

B1: =SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"1";$I$7:$I$100;">1") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"2";$I$7:$I$100;">0")

C1: =SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"1";$I$7:$I$100;">2") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"2";$I$7:$I$100;">1") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"3";$I$7:$I$100;">0")

D1: =SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"1";$I$7:$I$100;">3") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"2";$I$7:$I$100;">2") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"3";$I$7:$I$100;">1") + SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;"4";$I$7:$I$100;">0")

And so on....
```

How can I make this easier to do?

Comment: What about using named ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here.
Write in A1 and pull to the right:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100;$E$7:$E$100;INDEX(COLUMN($A$1:A$1);;);$I$7:$I$100;">" & INDEX(COLUMN(A1)-COLUMN($A$1:A$1);;)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working! I don't get how the INDEX function works without the row_num and col_num. Can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, INDEX is not needed here. I've use it only to evaluate numbers but SUMPRODUCT will do that anyway so it's enough to use: =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($D$7:$D$100,$E$7:$E$100,COLUMN($A$1:A$1),$I$7:$I$100,">" & COLUMN(A1)-COLUMN($A$1:A$1)))

Comment: Thanks, now I understood!